# Improving the accuracy of opencv in finding circles

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

So I have a few images that I need to extract the amount of white circles(with +90% accuracy) from and so far I've come up with this

[original image(has 183 circles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH1WN.jpg)

[and here's the result I get with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1yB.jpg)

as you can see it can detect about half of it but its not that accurate

the code so far:

```
def check_for_cells(img):
    found = 0
    found_list = []

    img = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    width, height = img.shape[:2]
    img = cv2.resize(img, (int(width/2), int(height/3)))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15,15), 0)
    histo_norm = cv2.equalizeHist(blurred) 
    _, th = cv2.threshold(blurred, 121, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 

    min_dist = 20
    param1 = 95
    param2 = 18
    minRadius = 3
    maxRadius = 14


    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(histo_norm, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, min_dist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
    circles_th = cv2.HoughCircles(th, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, min_dist, param1=79, param2=12, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0,:]:
            cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
            found_list.append([(i[0], i[1]), i[2]])
            found += 1


    if circles_th is not None:
        circles_th = np.uint16(np.around(circles_th))
        for i in circles_th[0,:]:
            if [(i[0], i[1]), i[2]] not in found_list:
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
                found_list.append([(i[0], i[1]), i[2]])
                found += 1


    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img, str(found), (0,100), font, 4, (0,0,0), 10)
    # print(found)

    cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help to improve the code would be appreciated!

Comment: The features you're trying to detect are far too small to be using Hough transform. Hough transform relies on having a significant number of boundary edges that lie on a circle, but with the resolution of your image and size of the features, you're only getting a few pixels on the boundary. Also, some of the features don't even appear to be circular. Instead I'd consider using basic morphological methods. Threshold the image to binary and detect disconnected regions of the area that you expect the features to be.

Comment: FindContours looks to be the name of the function in OpenCV for doing what I suggested. In Matlab I would use RegionProps.